# Filter bigint values on insert Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, int, bigint

I have 2 tables in Postgresql with the same schema, the only difference is that in one of the table id field is of type bigint. Schema of the table I need to fill with data looks like this:

```
create table test_int_table(
    id                          int,
    description             text,
    hash_code               int
);
```

I need to copy the data from test_table with bigint id to public.test_int_table. And some of the values which are bigger than id range should be filtered out. How can I track those values without hardcoding the range?
I can do something like this, but I would like to build more generic solution:

```
insert into test_int_table
select * from test_table as test
where test.id not between 2147483647 and 9223372036854775808
```

By generic I mean without constraints on the columns names and their number. So that in case, I have multiple columns of bigint type in other tables how can I filter all of their columns values generically (without specifying a column name)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic solution, as far as I can tell.

But I would write it as

```
INSERT INTO test_int_table
SELECT *
FROM test_table AS t
WHERE t.id BETWEEN -2147483647 AND 2147483647;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something  like this if you want to track :

Create a function like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert_to_integer(v_input bigint)
RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE v_int_value INTEGER DEFAULT NULL;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        v_int_value := v_input::INTEGER;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Invalid integer value: "%".  Returning NULL.', v_input;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
RETURN v_int_value;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and write a query like this :

```
INSERT INTO test_int_table SELECT * FROM test_table AS t WHERE convert_to_integer(t.id) is not null;
```

Or you can modify a function to return 0.